# Unserialize data from HTML inside JavaScript with pure JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm currently trying to unserialize data given from a HTML data attribute. The value comes as a serialized string from my DB.

To get the value I'm doing a readout out of my DB. After that I'm replacing any " by ' to prevent problems with the opening and closing tag inside HTML:

```
<span data-value="<?= str_replace( '"', "'", $obj->value ) ?>"
```

Here is an example how it finally looks like:

```
<span data-value="a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:'issue';s:4:'Test';s:10:'estimation';s:1:'5';}i:1;a:2:{s:5:'issue';s:4:'Impl';s:10:'estimation';s:1:'5';}}"></span>
```

My plan is now to receive the value in JS and transform it back to an array so that I can loop over it. I already tried `JSON.parse()` but that failed. Do you have any idea how to get this done?

**Update:**

Because some of you told me that my replace breaks my string, this here is the original one with an example:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
  let attr = $("span").attr("data-test");
  
  console.log(JSON.parse(attr));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-test='a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"issue";s:4:"Test";s:10:"estimation";s:1:"5";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"issue";s:4:"Impl";s:10:"estimation";s:1:"5";}}'></span>
```

Comment: Could please provide print($obj->value); here?

Comment: You may be better off unserializing it in PHP and then converting it to JSON before putting it in the `data-value` attribute.

Comment: Or just make a ajax request for the data on page load then handling the data in the java script

Comment: Your string replace breaks the unserialization

Comment: @NashPL In this case that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Have a look at how your string replace breaks it https://3v4l.org/gaJWs

Comment: @all I've added an example how it should work but it doesn't

Comment: Ah. A serialised string is not JSON, so that wont work.

Comment: Here, use JSON https://3v4l.org/q9mD4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse a serialised bit of data (not JSON) as JSON!

Instead just use JSON!

```
<?php

$x = 'a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"issue";s:4:"Test";s:10:"estimation";s:1:"5";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"issue";s:4:"Impl";s:10:"estimation";s:1:"5";}}';
$array = unserialize($x);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/Z3jJA

Now your thing will look like this:

```
<span data-value='[{"issue":"Test","estimation":"5"},{"issue":"Impl","estimation":"5"}]'></span>
```

Note that I used single quotes!

And your JS should work. :-)